# FOUC on light mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, darkmode

I'm having issues with a flash of unstyled ([FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)) content on my website. i have a button to switch between dark and light mode, with dark mode being default.

so when refreshing the page in light mode, you can see a FOUC of the dark mode before light mode is applied... i'm wondering how to stop that from happening.

```js
$(function() {
  var switched = $('#mode');

  switched.on("change", function() {
    if (switched.is(':checked')) {
      $('html').removeClass('dark');
      $('html').addClass('light');
      localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light');

    } else {
      $('html').removeClass('light');
      $('html').addClass('dark');
      localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark');

    }
  });

  var mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
  if (mode == 'dark') {
    switched.prop("checked", false);
    $('html').removeClass("light");
    $('html').addClass("dark");
  }
  if (mode == 'light') {
    switched.prop("checked", true);
    $('html').removeClass("dark");
    $('html').addClass("light");
  }

});
```

```css
:root,
:root.dark {
  --color-bg: #2B2531;
  --color-fg: #FAE5C4;
}

:root.light {
  --color-bg: #DED8F0;
  --color-fg: #2F2131;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
  color: var(--color-fg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <!--CSS then scripts are written here-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="boutonmode">
    <div class="darklightmode">
      <input type="checkbox" id="mode">
      <label for="mode" class="form-check-label">Mode</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>test</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What means "Fouc"?

Comment: @Reporter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Comment: "Flash of unstyled content", in my case it means the dark mode appears for a split second before light style is applied

Comment: "_CSS then scripts are written here_". Does this mean you've inline `style` tags in `head` instead of linking the stylesheets to external files?

Comment: No, I have an external stylesheet!

Comment: You'd need to wait for the JS to run before showing any content to avoid this, e.g. some sort of initial loading state that can be removed once the light/dark classes have been applied.